# Rescaled Diffusion Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Let $u(x,t)$ satisfy the diffusion equation $$u_{t}=Du_{xx}$$ for $0<x<a$, subject to the boundary conditions $$u(0,t)=u(a,t)=0.$$ In this expression, $D$ is the diffusion constant and $a$ is a length. Introduce new rescaled independent variables with $T=\dfrac{Dt}{a^2}$ and $X=\dfrac{x}{a}$ and put $u(x,t)=U(X,T)$. Show that the problem satisfied by the new unknown $U(X,T)$ is independent of $D$ and $a$.

I have gave an attempt to this problem, and found that the transformed boundary conditions are $U(0,T)=U(1,T)=0$. By looking for a solution in the form $U(X,T)=A(X)B(T)$ and using the separation of variables method, I arrived at $B(T)=Ce^{kDT}$ and $A(X)=Z\sin(\pi nX)$ for $k=\pi^2n^2$, $n\in\Bbb{N^+}$ and constants $C,Z$. Then finally by using the principle of superposition, this gives the general solution $U(X,T)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_ne^{-\pi^2 n^2DT}\sin(\pi nX)$.

This doesn't really help me with the problem, as my solution will still be dependent on $D$ and $a$, if I substitute back the scaled variables. I will appreciate any pointers I can get with this, as I am not sure whether I'm on the right track - thanks!

Comment: Your solution, expressed in original variables, will of course depend on $D$ and $a$. The point they're making is that the transformed diffusion equation, satisfied by $U(X,T)$, should not depend on $D$ or $a$. (I'm suspicious of your $B(T)$ for that reason. Your $A(X)$ is fine, by contrast.)

Comment: @Semiclassical For $B(T)$, I used the fact that from the original diffusion equation, we can directly arrive at $A(X)B'(T)=DA''(X)B(T)$ which gives $\dfrac{B'(T)}{DB(T)}=\dfrac{A''(X)}{A(X)}=k$ for some constant $k$ since the L.H.S. is a function of $t$ only and the R.H.S. is a function of $x$ only. Therefore $B'(T)=kDB(T)$ and this can be easily solved to obtain $B(T)=Ce^{kDT}$ for some constant $C$. I think this is the right procedure, unless I am mistaken?

Comment: It is mistaken. The easiest way to confirm this is to consider the dimensions: Since $D=u_{xx}/u_t$, $D$ must have dimensions of time/length^2. By contrast, $k=A''(X)/A(x)$ is dimensionless as is $T$. Therefore $kDT$ would have dimensions of time/length^2. But only dimensionless quantities can be exponentiated. The underlying issue is that you're assuming that $\partial_t B(T)=B'(T)$. This is false.